# detect which Event are in a HTML5 <video> element

Tags: html, api, events, video

How do you can detect which Event are in a HTML5  element available? 
For Exampe is the Event "onvolumechange" on IOS and Android Devices unavailable but in Firefox and Chrome on Desktop its work. How can you detect it? I've tried it so

```
if("onvolumechange" in document) {
 // DO ...
}
```

But it only works in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

According to the article, **[Everything You Need to Know About HTML5 Video and Audio](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2)**, the easiest way to probe for support is along the lines of:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
alert(video.canPlayType('video/ogg'));
```

The article goes on to say:

> There are several levels of support. First, the video element might
>   not be supported at all. This is the case for Opera 10.10 and IE8. For
>   this case, you can just put content inside the video element and it
>   will be rendered (in the above examples, the content is just "video
>   not supported"). No need to do anything further for this case.
>
> Second, the video element might be supported but the codecs you want
>   to use are not. Safari doesn't support Ogg/Theora/Vorbis, while Opera
>   and Firefox don't support MPEG-4/H.264/AAC. To detect this, you can
>   either use the canPlayType() method on a media element, or you could
>   have an onerror event listener; if a video fails to play because the
>   codec is not supported, an error event is fired.

As far as I can tell, there's no quick way to detect support for all the video related events (loadstart, progress, suspend, abort, error, emptied, stalled, loadedmetadata, loadeddata, canplay, canplaythrough, playing, waiting, seeking, seeked, ended, durationchange, timeupdate, play, pause, ratechange, and volumechange) without attempting to fire them first. In other words, try changing the volume and see if an error is returned.

Also note that the W3 has a nice page that demos event and property detection and firing of the <video> element at http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Not sure why you never received any up-votes or why the questioner didn't select your answer, but I've just given you a sympathy up-vote (also, your answer was really helpful!).